Lie algebra representation theory for subgroup of Lie group
I'm trying to study a certain $G$-representation $V$, for some subgroup $G$ of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$. Let $\{ a_1,...,a_n, b_1, ..., b_n \}$ be our symplectic basis with $a_i \cdot b_i = 1$. I know we can view $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$-representations as $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$-representations as well, and it would be helpful to be able to do this for $V$. My questions are:

Is there some $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $V$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-representation?
For fixed $i$, $G$ contains the element of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ that maps $b_i \rightarrow b_i + a_i$ and fixes all other basis elements. Which element of $\mathfrak{sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{C})$ does this correspond to? My guess is the one that (acting by derivations now) sends $b_i \rightarrow a_i$.


What is $\mathfrak g$? A lie subalgebra? The lie algebra of $G$? Is $G$ even a lie subgroup?

I assume that $G$ is a Lie subgroup of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ and that $\mathfrak{g}$ is its Lie algebra.
You can always take a Lie group representation $\pi:G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ and differentiate it to find a Lie algebra representation $d\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Note the converse is not true: there can be Lie algebra representations that aren't the derivative of one from the group (unless the group is simply connected).
Equally, you can always find representations of Lie subgroups/subalgebras by simply restricting the original representation to them.
However note that "corresponding elements" don't exist in general. We have differentiated the group representation not found an isomorphism between the group and the algebra. The exponential map will give you some approximation of this idea but it is not in general injective or surjective. In this case though the element $X$ which sends except $b_i\mapsto a_i$ and is $0$ on each basis element will exponentiate to the correct element of the group $\exp(X)$ which sends $b_i\mapsto b_i+a_i$ and is the identity on the other basis elements. Indeed for a Lie group representation $\pi$ with associated Lie algebra representation $d\pi$ we have $$\pi(\exp(X)) = \exp(d\pi(X)) = \mathrm{id} + d\pi(X) + \frac{1}{2!}(d\pi(X))^2 + \frac{1}{3!}(d\pi(X))^3 + \cdots$$
In this case, you should see $(d\pi(X))^2 = 0$ so the series terminates there and
$$\pi(\exp(X)) = \mathrm{id} + d\pi(X).$$
Note also that this isn't a derivation. Indeed that doesn't make sense as derivations are certain maps acting on algebras. For example, $\mathrm{ad}(X)$ is a derivation (by the Jacobi identity) but the usual action of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ has nothing to do with derivations.
